# MPMediaPickerController never shows on iOS 13, no error printed

Tags: ios, swift, mpmediapickercontroller

I am exploring the MPMediaPickerController for the first time, and I don't see anything when my button is pushed. The MPMediaPickerController.view has a frame after it is presented but it is not visible at all, nor does it appear in the view hierarchy. I am just using a simple fresh POC application with a ViewController and a IBOutlet button constrained to center vertical and horizontal, that calls this function:

```
    func checkMediaAccess() {
        let status = MPMediaLibrary.authorizationStatus()
        switch status {
        case .authorized:
            showMediaPicker()
        case .notDetermined:
            MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization() { status in
                if status == .authorized {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.showMediaPicker()
                    }
                }
            }
            break
        case .denied:
            print("Denied")
            break
        case .restricted:
            break
        @unknown default:
            break
        }

    }
```

Which then calls this function on authorized:

```
    func showMediaPicker() {
        print("SHOWING")
        let picker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .music)
        picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
        picker.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = pickerButton
        picker.showsCloudItems = true
        picker.delegate = self
        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print(picker.view.frame )
    }
```

"SHOWING" is printed, but again I don't see anything. I don't get anything else printed either.

I have all the info.plist descriptions for Media and Music access in. I also do get the prompt to allow the first time, and again "SHOWING" is printed. I have the delegates implemented, but they are never fired, because I don't see the view.

Nothing happens visually when I tap the button, and I can tap the button again.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe the music app not installed!

Comment: This was actually it. The Music app needs to be installed for this to work. I did not have it installed on my test phones, and it does not work on the simulator.